# (PHP) Getting content from a file that uses variables

Tags: php

Let's consider that mytext.txt contains:

> Hello my name is $name.

Then...

```
<?php
$name = "Johnny";
$output = file_get_contents("mytext.txt");
echo $output;
?>
```

I did this expecting $name to be replaced with the variable's value.

ps: I can't use include() because I need it to be stored in a variable.

Comment: very nice question. that kind of problem has crossed my mind for another project. you've got my vote for that and i think answers are clearly enough. may be you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Yo have to use output buffering, like so:

```
<?php
$name = "Johnny";
ob_start();
include "mytext.txt";
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $output;
?>
```

And you file must be formatted as php:

```
Hello, my name is <?php echo $name ?>
```

In that way, your include you file. Your file is handeled as php and you can store outputted html as variable.
More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: Just tried it. It displayed the same thing: Hello my name is $name.

Comment: If you need to keep the file format than you have to write somekindof template engine, what will `preg_replace()` or `str_replace()` to remplate variables. Or use some templating engine: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/

Answer (score 1):

use the pregmatch at all will be god way, here is the working example that i have tried before, just delete the `$`  and change to `[name]` from your var

```
<?php
$name = "Johnny";
$output = file_get_contents("data.txt");
echo preg_replace('/\[name\]/',$name,$output);
?>
```

and the mytext.txt just put like this `Hello my name is [name].`

and the result will be `Hello my name is Jhonny.`

Comment: The it will output `Hemmo my Jonnhy is Jonhhy` :)

Comment: It's not a bad idea. But my post just showed an example. In my web app there's actually a text file with LOTS of variables, so I would need a preg_replace for every variable which doesnt seem like a very good approach.

Comment: just use an array to replace them all, this quit easy isn't ? using `pattern as an array` and the `replacement as an array` is the good way, you don' have to use `preg_replace()` for every variable, just use an array for both `patter`n and `replacement`

Comment: I would do it using preg_replace_callback. First matching all variable patterns from file and then replacinh them usin dynamic variables.

Answer (score 0):

**mytext.txt**

```
<?php
$str = "Hello my name is $name.";
```

**your.php**

```
<?php
$name = "Johnny";
require_once 'mytext.txt';
echo $str;
```